# Why does my code not allow me to loop a certain section of code, instead looping the entire code?

Tags: python, loops

So I am currently creating a small stock broker game using python for an assignment I have, and I have hit a problem. My next lesson isn't until Tuesday next week, and I can't seem to find any good solutions to my issue. Basically, this code is intended to initially decrease the time by 1 every time the player decides to wait a day, however the time remains at 20 no matter how many times the player waits. I am also unsure of how to make it so that my code loops the user input section: "Did you want to buy stocks, sell stocks or wait a day?" Until the user says he would like to wait. Is there a fix for this issue, and if so, what is it?Here is the code I am talking about:

````py
stocks = 0
time = 21
money = 100
print("You have $" + str(money) + " in your bank.")  
while time > 0:
    stock = random.randint(1,20)
    time = time - 1
    while True:        
        print("You have " + str(time) + " days remaining until the market closes")
        print("Stocks are currently worth: $" + str(stock)) 
        choice = input("Did you want to buy stocks, sell stocks or wait a day?  ")
        if choice.casefold() == "buy":       
            while True:
                numberBuy = int(input("Enter the number of stocks that you would like to buy:  "))
                if numberBuy * stock > money:
                    print("You don't have the money for that")
                else:
                    break
            money = money - (numberBuy * stock)
            stocks = stocks + numberBuy
            print("You bought " + str(numberBuy) + " stocks and you spent $" + str(numberBuy * stock) + " buying them. You now have $" + str(money) + " and you have " + str(stocks) + " stocks")
        elif choice.casefold() == "sell":
            while True:
                numberSell = int(input("Enter the number of stocks that you would like to sell:  "))
                if numberSell > stocks:
                    print("You don't have enough stocks for that. You have " + str(stocks) + " stocks and you want to sell " + str(numberSell))
                else:
                    break
            stocks = stocks - numberSell
            money = money + (numberSell * stock)
            print("You sold " + str(numberSell) + " stocks and you made $" + str(numberSell * stock) + " selling them. You now have $" + str(money) + " and you have " + str(stocks) + " stocks")
        elif choice.casefold() == "wait" or "wait a day" or "wait day":
            print("You wait for the next day to come. At the end of the day, you have $" + str(money) + " in your bank account and you have " + str(stocks) + " stocks to")
            print("your name")
            print(" ")
            print("===========================================================================================================")
            print(" ")```
````

Comment: It would help if you would [edit] your post to add a tag for the specific programming language you're using. It would also be good for you to learn to use a debugger, so you can step through the code line by line and examine varianbles and the flow of execution. It will help you solve the vast majority of problems you'll encounter. It's never too early to learn to use the most valuable tool a programmer has available.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `time` never changes is because all of the code based on user input choices is in a second while loop, which currently has no form of exit. A quick fix is to move the line `time = time - 1` to the appropriate option in the if statement. Also I think you should remove the second while loop entirely, because the stock price will never change.

```
while time > 0:
    stock = random.randint(1,20)
    print("You have " + str(time) + " days remaining until the market closes")
    print("Stocks are currently worth: $" + str(stock)) 
    choice = input("Did you want to buy stocks, sell stocks or wait a day?  ")
    if choice.casefold() == "buy":       
        while True:
            numberBuy = int(input("Enter the number of stocks that you would like to buy:  "))
            if numberBuy * stock > money:
                print("You don't have the money for that")
            else:
                break
        money = money - (numberBuy * stock)
        stocks = stocks + numberBuy
        print("You bought " + str(numberBuy) + " stocks and you spent $" + str(numberBuy * stock) + " buying them. You now have $" + str(money) + " and you have " + str(stocks) + " stocks")
    elif choice.casefold() == "sell":
        while True:
            numberSell = int(input("Enter the number of stocks that you would like to sell:  "))
            if numberSell > stocks:
                print("You don't have enough stocks for that. You have " + str(stocks) + " stocks and you want to sell " + str(numberSell))
            else:
                break
        stocks = stocks - numberSell
        money = money + (numberSell * stock)
        print("You sold " + str(numberSell) + " stocks and you made $" + str(numberSell * stock) + " selling them. You now have $" + str(money) + " and you have " + str(stocks) + " stocks")
    elif choice.casefold() == "wait" or "wait a day" or "wait day":
        time = time - 1
        print("You wait for the next day to come. At the end of the day, you have $" + str(money) + " in your bank account and you have " + str(stocks) + " stocks to")
        print("your name")
        print(" ")
        print("===========================================================================================================")
        print(" ")
```